# Cat's back twitching A LOT for over 4 hours now

Tags: cats, behavior, health, parasites

Today my father and I bathed my cat. He's going to be 1 year old in a couple months and this afternoon we noticed that his back (the entire back half of his body) started twitching. Sometimes the spasms are light, but sometimes they are so strong that it looks like he's going to explode.

I am familiar with feline hyperesthesia since it's the only thing I could find on the Internet.

I don't know if he is being hyperactive (he always was, to be honest). I noticed him licking his back once (a few seconds ago); he's not running or rolling, or if he did I did not see it. My mother says he can't stay quiet
today.

A few hours after the bath, I noticed his skin was very warm, probably febrile, but I don't know if he was like that before the bath. I didn't see him a lot today because I have to study for tests that will take place tomorrow.

We will take him to the vet once we can, but I'd like some ideas of what it could be.

Edit: extra information that might help

- I have noticed today while bathing him that his lower belly is swollen, like there's fluid in it, my father noticed it a long time ago but because of his fur, I did not.
- We usually play a bit aggressively, that is I pet him while he's laid down in a playful way and he usually grabs my hand and starts licking and scratching, biting it etc, it usually hurts but not so much, after all he's not doing it on purpose. However, right now when I was petting him he grabbed my hand in a way that hurt a lot, almost like he was trying to defend himself.

Edit 2: Forgot to mention, the spasms are constant, they stop but 3 seconds later they are back.

- I've just noticed that he's breathing very quickly and he just jumped on my table and laid down on my mousepad (he never does this) and he's currently sleeping where my mouse should be, he closes his eyes but then a very strong spasms wakes him up (it's happening as I am writing this) he appears to be very tired but can't sleep because of the spasms

He had a history of ear mites (*Otodectes cynotis*) infestation about 2 months ago, and I noticed his ear is twitching, which was a symptom back then.

Can I do anything to relieve him of this discomfort?

Edit 3: Guys, something's wrong, he's not moving, it's like he's very tired. I picked him up and usually he hates it, but now he's not doing anything, he just stays like I put him.

Comment: Guy's, his ear and head are twitching, just like it was when he got ear mites, and he's biting everything he can see, trying to chew it, just like he did it as well

Comment: take it to a vet right now or your cat will die,in fact it probably is too late to save your cat by now.

Comment: Hey guys, just a quick update, a few moments after i made the post i found a way to take him to a nearby vet hospital, once we got there they did an ultrassound and a x-ray, both came back unconclusive because of gas, so we were told to go there again tomorrow (today at morning here) but 1 hour after we got back home his condition worsened.

He was hyperactive, couldn't stay quiet for a second, biting his tail, rolling down from side to side, moving unquietly,, chewing on everything, so we got him there again, and they didn't know what it could be so they addmited him

Comment: They have no idea of what happened to him so they are going to treat the symptoms, im going to have more news about him in 2 or 3 hours

Comment: @Spacey i am hoping you can give some good news about your cat,it is best if you edit the update into the question so people know what to do if they ever gets into the same situation.

Answer (score 11):

The only answer is to TAKE IT TO THE VET RIGHT NOW. This sounds dangerous so you need to GO TO THE VET NOW.

Nobody on the internet can tell you for sure what is wrong. A vet needs to examine your cat to treat it GO TO THE VET.

Your cats life is in your hands, so please, TAKE IT TO THE VET.

Answer (score 2):

to anyone wondering what it was, it turned out to be the shampoo we were using on him, it didn't react well, once we stopped using it, it never happened again. Sadly he's not with us anymore but he survived many things.

Answer (score -2):

She could be very cold. Try putting her under blankets or something. If that does not fix it head to the vet.

Comment: he's not cold and unfortunately i really can't take him to a vet right now

Comment: Could it be fever/shivering? I'd put her under blankets, set the thermostat a bit high... She can avoid your attempts if she is not cold. Still take her to the vet whenever you can.

Comment: He's not avoiding me at all, like i said on the edit, he's letting me do whatever i want with him, if i pick him up he tries to sleep on my arms (he hates being picked up)